# Strange issue with NextJS and NextAuth

Tags: typescript, authentication, next.js, next-auth

I have the following auth setup for NextJS using a custom token provider/service. I am following this [guide](https://dev.to/mabaranowski/nextjs-authentication-jwt-refresh-token-rotation-with-nextauthjs-5696) and my code looks like

```
async function refreshAccessToken(authToken: AuthToken) {
    try {
        const tokenResponse = await AuthApi.refreshToken(authToken.refresh_token);
        return new AuthToken(
            tokenResponse.access_token,
            tokenResponse.token_type,
            tokenResponse.expires_in,
            tokenResponse.refresh_token
        );

    } catch (error) {
        return new AuthToken(
            authToken?.access_token,
            authToken?.token_type,
            authToken?.expires_in,
            authToken?.refresh_token,
            "An error occurred whilst refreshing token"
        );
    }
}

export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
    providers: [
        CredentialsProvider({
            name: 'credentials',
            credentials: {
                username: { label: 'Username', type: 'text' },
                password: { label: 'Password', type: 'password' }
            },
            authorize: async (credentials) => {
                try {
                    if (!credentials) {
                        return null;
                    }

                    const { username, password } = credentials;
                    const authToken = await AuthApi.login(username, password);

                    const session: Session = new Session(authToken, null);
                    if (authToken != null && authToken.error == '') {
                        const userDetails = await AuthApi.getUserDetails(authToken.access_token);
                        if (userDetails != null) {
                            session.user = userDetails;
                        }
                    }
                    console.log(session);
                    return session as any;

                } catch (error) {
                    console.error(error);
                    throw error;
                }
            }
        })
    ],
    session: {
        strategy: 'jwt',
        maxAge: Constants.AccessTokenLifetimeSeconds
    },
    secret: process.env.APP_SECRET,
    jwt: {
        secret: process.env.APP_SECRET,
        maxAge: Constants.AccessTokenLifetimeSeconds
    },
    pages: { signIn: '/login' },
    callbacks: {
        jwt: async ({ user }: any) => {
    
            let token: AuthToken | null = null;

            if (user != null && user.token != null) {

                token = user.token;

                const clock = new Clock();
                if (user.token.expiry_date_time < clock.nowUtc()) {
                    token = await refreshAccessToken(user.token);
                }
            }
            console.log("OO", user, token);
            return token;
        },
        session: async ({ session, user, token }) => {
            //session.user = user;
            //session.token = token;
            return session;
        }
    }
};
export default NextAuth(authOptions);
```

The relevent classes are

```
export default class AuthToken implements IAuthToken {

    public expiry_date_time: Date;

    constructor(
        public access_token: string,
        public token_type: string,
        public expires_in: number,
        public refresh_token: string,
        public error: string = ""
    ) {
        const clock = new Clock();
        this.expiry_date_time = new Date(
            clock.nowUtc().getTime() + (this.expires_in - 60) * 1000
        );
    }
}
```

and

```
export default class Session implements ISession {
    constructor(
        public token: AuthToken | null,
        public user: UserDetails | null
    ) { }
}
```

But in the callback, I am getting the following error

> error - TypeError: JWT Claims Set MUST be an object
> at new ProduceJWT (C:\VRPM\Repos\portal\node_modules\jose\dist\node\cjs\jwt\produce.js:10:19)
> at new EncryptJWT (C:\VRPM\Repos\portal\node_modules\jose\dist\node\cjs\jwt\encrypt.js:7:1)
> at Object.encode (C:\VRPM\Repos\portal\node_modules\next-auth\jwt\index.js:49:16)
> at async Object.callback (C:\VRPM\Repos\portal\node_modules\next-auth\core\routes\callback.js:429:22)
> at async NextAuthHandler (C:\VRPM\Repos\portal\node_modules\next-auth\core\index.js:295:28)
> at async NextAuthNextHandler (C:\VRPM\Repos\portal\node_modules\next-auth\next\index.js:23:19)
> at async C:\VRPM\Repos\portal\node_modules\next-auth\next\index.js:59:32
> at async Object.apiResolver (C:\VRPM\Repos\portal\node_modules\next\dist\server\api-utils\node.js:184:9)
> at async DevServer.runApi (C:\VRPM\Repos\portal\node_modules\next\dist\server\next-server.js:403:9)
> at async Object.fn (C:\VRPM\Repos\portal\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:493:37) {
> page: '/api/auth/[...nextauth]'

and I have no idea how to resolve as the data I am returning *is an object*:

```
 token: AuthToken {
    access_token: '...Nn_ooqUtFvdfh53k',
    token_type: 'Bearer',
    expires_in: 86400,
    refresh_token: '...ZddCpNTc',
    error: '',
    expiry_date_time: 2023-02-09T19:29:15.307Z
  }
```

Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong here?

---

I have found that if I return

```
return { 
    token: token
};
```

the error goes away, but what is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing I noticed in all examples of next-auth implementations is that the `authorize()` function is meant to return the user's details (id, email, etc), not an object containing a `token` & `user` details.

It seems like you are incorrectly relying on the token from this user object under the `jwt()` callback when it should be derived from the callback itself.

I've setup a `Next.js` + `next-auth` sandbox and I'm stepping through your code now.

**Instead of this:**

```js
jwt: async ({ user }: any) => {
  let token = user.token;

  if (user != null && user.token != null) {
      const clock = new Clock();
      if (user.token.expiry_date_time < clock.nowUtc()) {
          token = await refreshAccessToken(user.token);
      }
  }
  return token;
},
```

**Do this:**

```js
jwt: async ({ token, user }: any) => {

  // at login, save user token to jwt token
  if (user) {
    token.accessToken = user.token.accessToken;
    token.accessTokenExpiry = user.token.accessTokenExpiry;
    token.refreshToken = user.token.refreshToken;
  }
  
  // check if we should refresh the token
  const shouldRefreshTime = user.token.expiry_date_time < clock.nowUtc();
  if (shouldRefreshTime) {
    token = refreshAccessToken(token);
  }

  // return the token
  return Promise.resolve(token);
},
```

Also inside `authorize()`:

**Change this from:**

`return session;`

**To:**

`return session.user`;

**Important change** in the `jwt()` callback:

`jwt: async ({ user }: any) => {`

**To:**

`jwt: async ({ token, user }: any) => {`

Additionally, your `session()` callback should not be returning the `refreshToken`. They mention this security concern in their [docs](https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/callbacks#session-callback).

The `session()` callback should be updated.

**From this:**

```
session: async ({ session, user, token }) => {
   //session.user = user;
   //session.token = token;
   return session; <--- entire token (refreshToken, etc) being returned...
}
```

**To this:**

```
session: async ({ session, user, token }) => {

   // Send properties to the client, like an access_token and user from a provider.
   session.accessToken = token.accessToken;
   session.user = user;

   return session
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time... Just an FYI - the check `!= null` checks for both `undefined` and `null`. I will read the rest of your answer now...

Comment: This does not solve what is going on unfortunately.

Comment: Good point - I overuse `!==` to a fault in that I missed that small detail when reviewing. Updating my answer - I think I found the issue.

Comment: Hi Wes, thank you for this and for your time, I have been away, so sorry for the delayed upvote etc. Happy to accept this. I have made some changes, but I am still concerned, any chance you could glance your eye over this - a code review question based on my final implementation? https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/283281/nextjs-nextauth-implementation-using-custom-token-source